# If a non-caster uses a magic item to cast the Wish spell, but becomes "unable to cast Wish ever again", can they no longer use the item to do so?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, wish

If the *wish* spell is used to do anything other than duplicate a lower-level spell, then "there is a 33 percent chance that you are unable to cast *wish* ever again". Does this apply if a non-caster uses a magic item that can cast *wish* in other ways, such as a fighter using a *ring of three wishes*?

In other words: If the fighter fails that roll for the first *wish* and becomes "unable to cast *wish* ever again", would they be unable to use the other two castings of *wish* from the ring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the specific phrasing of the magic item's description.

Specifically for the [*Ring of Three Wishes*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4735-ring-of-three-wishes), it says (DMG, p. 193)

> While wearing this ring, **you** can use an action to expend 1 of its 3 charges to **cast the *wish* spell** from it. [...]

It is specific that you cast the spell; any consequences of doing so would apply to you. So, for example if you got the "can never cast *wish* again" on the first try, then the item is now useless to you except as bling.

This is a "specific beats general" situation. In general, a non-caster can't cast spells, but this specific item allows them to cast *wish*; except as modified (e.g. no material components, since they're casting it from a magic item), normal rules apply.

I haven't looked, but it may be the same for all magic items.